# Customize tabs on Lightning page layouts for different record types?

Tags: lightning-experience

Is there a way to customize an object record page in lightning? I want certain tabs to appear on certain record types.

Thanks, I'm new to the app builder and lightning.

Comment: using lightning app builder you can include lightning components embedded inside lightning tabs, and also you can include buttons in the form of lightning actions. 
Inside your lightning components , you need to implement certain interfaces to make it available as lightning tabs and for lightning app builder.

Comment: when you say tabs- are you trying to say lightning standard tab component and their visibility?

Comment: I apparently must have 50 rep to comment, but Itai, is there any chance you could provide a screenshot of the steps afterwards? You have your comment saying "Find and assign your record pages." I see "find." I don't see "assign." Additionally, Salesforce cuts off the bottom of the page in Chrome, so I have to apply some shenanigans to see what's below that search box. I wouldn't ask unless I haven't already nearly exhausted all of Google. I'm missing something. I only see steps to change the default layout, or steps to add a page when one hasn't already been assigned, which is useless to me.

Comment: @user3054804 Welcome to SFSE! This was a useful comment so I converted it before it got removed by the community at large as not being an answer. Please do register and join us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a different record pages for each record type.

After that click on the `View Page Assignment` to define each one for each record type:

[image]

There you can see which record page is assigned to which app, record type and profile:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

record types work the same way as in salesforce classic. Ideally, You can enhance the view of the normal salesforce classic page with the help of lightning app builder and lightning tabs. To do this you have to create lightning components.

Other existing related lists, related records components can be included. Check the lightning app builder for more information on this.

```
<aura:component controller="classname" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
</aura:component>
```

> flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes ==> LC is available for both record
>   pages and any other type of page.
>
> flexipage:availableForRecordHome ==> LC is designed just for record
>   pages
>
> force:hasRecordId ==> LC needs the record ID
>
> force:hasSObjectName ==> LC needs the object’s API name
>
> force:appHostable ==> to host LC as Custom tabs in LE and to add your
>   LC to App Launcher